# what are the things to know when embeding pdf on my website

Tags: html, pdf

i want to embed a pdf file to my website. the pdf file is located beside the html file. i searched on this website and found many way to do it. but it's not working for me i tried many example and some of the examples are not working also. the pdf file is not showing. i have internet download manager installed and if i go to the demo website of how to show the pdf file. the IDM keeps on downloading it and now showing the content on the web page.

i have this sample code. can someone point out what am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed src="1.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>

</body>
</html>
```

code update:
im now using iframe

```
<iframe src = "1.pdf" width = "100%" height = "100%"> </iframe>
```

i even installed adobe pdf plugin for firefox in my browser. but when i reload the website im creating. it says "this pdf document might not be displayed correctly"

but when i check other's demo page for embeding pdf file online. i can see their pdf. but on my localhost i can't see mine? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Did you try a solution based on **iframe** HTML tag? Disclaimer: I am a total HTML noob.

Comment: the question is updated

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="1.pdf">Download</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although unclear, I don't think this answers OP's question. He seems to want to **embed** a pdf file, not just point an anchor to it.

Comment: Due to the question isnt very clear at all, I first thought this might be what he was looking for. But I guess you are right @fanton.